# Reverse iterators (one before the first element) and undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, undefined-behavior

When dealing with pointers, pointers to one past the end have (mostly) defined behavior:

```
int array[8];
int* x = array + 8; // Still considered pointing to part of array in expressions
```

Iterators make use of this by comparing the iterator pointer to the one past the end.

Reverse iterators do the same thing, but to one before the start of the array:

```
int array[8];
int* x = array - 1;
```

Isn't this undefined behavior? Do containers hold an extra element and consider `[1]` the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse iterators aren't really iterators. They're more like "iterator adapters". You can call the `base()` member function on a reverse iterator in order to get a real iterator back, and this incurs a -1 offset, so that `rbegin().base() == end()` and `rend().base() == begin()`. Therefore, there is no need for an explicit "before the beginning" pointer value or something like that. (With the exception of `forward_list` of course.)

Comment: "_Reverse iterators aren't really iterators._" what are real iterators?

Comment: @curiousguy: Iterators are opaque objects. Reverse iterators are wrappers around decrementable iterators.

Comment: @curiousguy: [Reverse_iterator is an iterator adaptor](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ReverseIterator.html)

Comment: @KerrekSB "_Iterators are opaque objects_" so, a list iterator which gives public access to the node pointer would not be an iterator? So the concept of Iterator is defined **negatively**?

Comment: @LokiAstari "model of: Random Access Iterator" QED

Comment: This makes sense, but is the behavior still defined? It seems like some invalid pointer arithmetic must be happening during the conversion.

Comment: @Pubby: As the standard library is part of the compiler; The writers of the standard library are allowed to make assumptions about how the compiler works (assumptions that application developers can't make).

Comment: @LokiAstari "_That's correct. But completely irrelevant._" what is correct and irrelevant?

Comment: @Pubby "_This makes sense, but is the behavior still defined?_" Yes. "_It seems like some invalid pointer arithmetic must be happening during the conversion_" It does not happen.

Comment: @LokiAstari I understand that, but wouldn't this mean that all user-defined iterators have UB?

Comment: @LokiAstari "_As the standard library is part of the compiler; The writers of the standard library are allowed to make assumptions about how the compiler works (assumptions that application developers can't make)._" That's correct. But completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Pubby "_but wouldn't this mean that all user-defined operators have UB?_" No, Loki is wrong here. The reverse iterator adaptor was designed so that no invalid arithmetic is ever done. The price is that: 1) is inefficient; 2) it is strange invalidation behaviour

Comment: @curiosguy Are you sure it's valid? It seems like converting begin() to a reverse iterator involves invalid arithmetic.

Comment: @Pubby: converting `begin()` to a reverse iterator will give you a reverse iterator whose base is `begin()` - nothing invalid happens here. It's only invalid to *dereference* that iterator; this will involve trying to access `*(base()-1)`, which is invalid for two reasons.

Comment: Now that I think about it it makes sense, although it is a silly hack.

Comment: @MikeSeymour "_It's only invalid to dereference that iterator_" Yes, and it is not unexpected: `reverse(begin())` is `rend()`: it is the one-past-the-end (reverse) iterator.

Comment: @curiousguy: About your second comment ("iterators defined negatively"): I can't tell if you're joking, but being opaque doesn't preclude you from knowing the interna. It just means you don't *have* to know them. All you need to know about iterators is that you can increment them, and that you can get information out of them by plugging them into `iterator_traits`. By contrast, a reverse iterator is "transparently" defined in terms of its innards.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am not joking at all, and I wonder if you are. Iterators are defined by what they can do (positive definition), not by what they cannot do (negative definition). "_but being opaque doesn't preclude you from knowing the interna._" So exposing `base` doesn't mean a reverse iterator is not an iterator. "_By contrast, a reverse iterator is "transparently" defined in terms of its innards._" By contrast to what? Anyway, the linked documentation clearly says that a reverse **iterator** is an **iterator**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard [24.4.1/1] the relationship between the reverse iterator and the base is:

```
&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)
```

So no, there isn't any padding before the start of the array. And the above method is defined behavior according to the standard.

Comment: It does not matter to you that the behaviour is not defined?

Comment: Negative indices are allowed: &a[i] is an address calculation which evaluates as (a + i), so &a[-i] evaluates as (a - i). If you have int i[8], and int *p = i + 4, p[-2] is perfectly fine. Thats how pointers work. Accessing memory outside the bounds of the array is undefined though.

Comment: `&a[i]` is `&*(a+i)`. It does a **dereference**. "_If you have int i[8], and int *p = i + 4, p[-2] is perfectly fine._" Exactly.

Comment: @curiousguy Can you provide any examples of pointer arithmetic with negative indices being compiled to instructions that actually access the memory? It sounds sort of made up that a compiler would actually dereference the pointer, and hence I'm not going to bother looking it up in the standard.

Comment: @curiousguy Uhh, I doubt it -- show me a compiler that actually does the dereference. Like I said, it sounds made up.

Comment: "_Can you provide any examples of pointer arithmetic with negative indices being compiled to instructions that actually access the memory?_" It did _not_ say that memory would be accessed. "_It sounds sort of made up that a compiler would actually dereference the pointer_" It **is made up** as in "made up by the ISO standard"

Comment: @curiousguy So if the memory isn't accessed, why is the behavior undefined?

Comment: "_show me a compiler that actually does the dereference_" You are confusing types of requirements. **You** are doing a dereference, not the compiler. The requirement to write correct C++ programs is on you, not the compiler. **The compiler is required to generate correct code for correct C++ programs.** This is not a correct C++ program, so **there is no requirement on the compiler**; IOW, **you have UB**.

Comment: "_So if the memory isn't accessed, why is the behavior undefined?_" because you are dereferencing a pointer, and this pointer does not point to an object. **The definition of the behaviour of `*p` is that if `p` = `&a`, you get `a`.**

Comment: But that's just it, you're *not* doing the dereference. Dereferencing happens at runtime, and expression parsing happens at compile time. So you think `a[b]` evaluates before `&()` (it does), and it evaluates to  two steps: 1) compute a + b, and 2) dereference the result. *But* the next operation is `&()`, whose effect is to *omit step two of the previous operation,* since that step is a dereference. Or you can think of it as the dereferenced value becomes unused (like it can in postfix `++`) which disappears when it's time to generate assembly. Either way, no dereference at runtime.

Comment: Comparisons between pointers should point to the same object. `a-1 == p` where p points to an element of `a` is undefined.

Comment: "_you're not doing the dereference_" of course I am doing a dereference. What I am doing when I compute `*p`? "_So you think a[b] evaluates before &() (it does), and it evaluates to two steps:_" Not only me, the language definition "think" the same way. "_whose effect is to omit step two of the previous operation_" to "omit" something? that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @curiousguy Can you provide some citations? Where should I be looking in the standard, and which one?

Comment: You seem extremely confused by what the standard requires. Please read again my comment which says "_You are confusing types of requirements._ (...)"

Comment: `a-1 == p` is defined as `false` since `p` is not in `a`, i.e. `p` does not equal any `a+k` where `k` is an integer between 0 and `N-1`, where `N` is the number of elements in `a`. This proceeds from the definition of an array.

Comment: "_Can you provide some citations?_" citation for what?

Comment: @curiousguy Some citations to support your arguments. What else?

Comment: @AnthonyBlake some citation to support which statement?

Comment: Quote from standard for reference: *"If two pointers p and q of the same type point to diﬀerent objects that are not members of the same
object or elements of the same array or to diﬀerent functions, or if only one of them is null, the results
of p<q, p>q, p<=q, and p>=q are unspeciﬁed."*, *"The == (equal to) and the != (not equal to) operators have the same semantic restrictions, conversions, and
result type as the relational operators except for their lower precedence and truth-value result."*

Comment: @pubby That sounds a lot less crazy than curiousguy's argument. But why then did you have to ask "Isn't this undefined behavior?"

Comment: @AnthonyBlake I wanted to know if reverse iterators were defined as it seems like they break the rules.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake From N3242: 1.1 Scope [intro.scope]
This International Standard specifies requirements for implementations of the C++ programming language.
The first such requirement is that they implement the language, and so this International Standard also
defines C++.

Comment: 1.4 Implementation compliance [intro.compliance]/2
Although this International Standard states only requirements on C++ implementations, those requirements
are often easier to understand if they are phrased as requirements on programs, parts of programs, or
execution of programs. Such requirements have the following meaning:
— If a program contains no violations of the rules in this International Standard, a conforming implementation
shall, within its resource limits, accept and correctly execute that program.

Comment: @Pubby http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ReverseIterator.html#3 "The variable rfirst is initialized as reverse_iterator<...> rfirst(V.end());. The value obtained when it is dereferenced, however, is *(V.end() - 1). This is a general property: the fundamental identity of reverse iterators is &*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1). "

Comment: @curiousguy well done.. that is indeed some text from a C++ standard -- albeit somewhat non-sequitur

Comment: @AnthonyBlake It is some text to explain what the C++ standard is about. Some people here were confused about its scope, that's why I am quoting these.

Comment: @curiousguy You should have just said "the fundamental identity of reverse iterators is &*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)" 30 mins ago.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake Yes, but I was busy explaining **you** the scope and meaning of the C++ standard. Also, Loki gave the link to SGI STL 57 min ago.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake N3242: undefined behavior "**behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements**" "[ Note: Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any explicit definition of behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data."

Comment: @curiousguy yes, but can you prove (i.e., provide a machine verifiable proof) that *any* compiler exhibits unintended behavior in the case of a reverse iterator that doesn't adjust the base?

Comment: @curiousguy Or even just provide an example -- don't worry about the formal proof =) Putting aside the *unintended* behavior, I'm curious if any compiler does actually produce faulty code with a reverse iterator that does point to the element before the base of the array.

Comment: @curiousguy Unless their is a compiler that generates faulty code, we can *quantitively* say that the behavior *is* defined.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake Total, absolute, nonsense.

Comment: @curiousguy So what you are saying is that you can't find any examples or proofs of incorrect behavior, and thus the behavior *is* quantitatively defined?

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "_but can you prove (i.e., provide a machine verifiable proof) that any compiler exhibits unintended behavior in the case of a reverse iterator that doesn't adjust the base?_" Very easy: just use a checked iterator.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "_So what you are saying is that you can't find any examples or proofs of incorrect behavior, and thus the behavior is quantitatively defined?_" Utter nonsense. You are wasting my time here.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "_I'm curious if any compiler does actually produce faulty code with a reverse iterator that does point to the element before the base of the array._" I am curious if you can quote any compiler documentation which says such usage is allowed.

Comment: @curiousguy "Very easy: just use a checked iterator." -- what compiler was that? A made up one?

Comment: @curiousguy And what was the incorrect behavior that was resulted?

Comment: @AnthonyBlake Please educate yourself about "checked iterators".

Comment: @curiousguy I'm being totally serious here: can you give me a real world example of incorrect behavior when using a reverse iterator? Or can't you?

Comment: @curiousguy I'm *not* asking for details on checked iterators, I'm asking for a real example of incorrect behavior that would justify the existence and use of checked iterators

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "_can you give me a real world example of incorrect behavior when using a reverse iterator?_" A checked iterator will abort when used with a broken reverse iterator that does not adjust the base pointer properly.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "_that would justify the existence and use of checked iterators_" again, educate yourself. Checked iterators are justified by the desire to detect bugs.

Comment: @curiousguy Yes -- but would the behavior have been incorrect *without* the checked iterator? In other words, is the checked iterator actually preventing a real fault? Or is it just stopping compilation for no reason? The checked iterator exists to prevent behavior we *cannot* be certain of, but I'm asking you if you can provide an example where we *can* be certain of incorrect behavior. What I'm saying is quite simple: undefined behavior does not prove that incorrect behavior will occur with a reverse iterator.

Comment: @curiousguy Let me try it another way: undefined behavior simply means you cannot prove correctness, but it does not imply incorrectness.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm *not* doubting that checked iterators are bad! I'm simply saying that in this case -- the reverse iterator -- it is entirely plausible that there is actually no way incorrect behavior could occur. I'm not trying to say that trying to prevent bugs is bad, I'm simply asking questions.. as I say, undefined behavior is *not* incorrect behavior -- it is quite possible that formal methods could be used to prove that the behavior is always correct in this case, and we could allow programmers more freedom.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake for example: loading an invalid address value in an address register can trigger an exception on some CPU.

Comment: @curiousguy What CPU? Not x86 or ARM.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake (...) "_we could allow programmers more freedom_" for example, you might want to allow `int a[2]; int *p = a - 1;` Then you also want `p < a`. But on a segmented architecture, if `a` is at the beginning of the segment, you might have `p > a` (wrap-around on `a - 1`). To preserve ordering, the implementation could either: allocate a dummy one-before-the-end element, or manage to never allocate arrays at the beginning of a segment. Both solutions would require non-trivial changes to the compiler, and could cause problems in practice.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "_What CPU?_" x86

Comment: @curiousguy Interesting, but if you do a signed comparison with the pointers it isn't a problem (the wrap around is negative). Of course the signed comparison does impose other problems, but with 48-bit addressing or whatever, it could be worked around.

Comment: @curiousguy I was only aware of an x86 exception where you try and access memory.. what exception can occur when you load an address?

Comment: @AnthonyBlake There are many memory mode supported by 8086. Under the segmented mode, the offset is a 16 bit unsigned number. Of course this mode is not used any more on general-use computers (but could be used on special purpose or old hardware). Anyway, pointer arithmetic had to be compatible (and efficiently implementable) on those segmented modes of operation.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake With a segmented architecture, in far pointer mode, a pointer consists of a segment and an offset. So the (logical) address register actually consists of the segment register and the actual register which holds the offset value. Loading an invalid segment value will cause a trap with Intel processors.

Comment: @curiousguy Well it was nice talking to you -- I agree that it is probably best to enforce checked iterators and so on, but it was interesting to think about the other possibilities. As I said, it might be possible to prove correctness of a reverse iterator with some provisos -- but it would be a lot of effort and probably impractical.

Comment: @curiousguy That trap could then be used to determine that the pointer had wrapped around though, right? So handling the trap would actually help the reverse iterator handle the situation of the array starting at the base of the segment

Comment: @AnthonyBlake "_That trap could then be used to determine that the pointer had wrapped around though, right?_" handling a trap is complicated. I think it cannot be done in user mode (ring 3). And it is extremely costly too, compared to normal pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @curiousguy "handling a trap is complicated. I think it cannot be done in user mode (ring 3). And it is extremely costly too, compared to normal pointer arithmetic" right.. I would think it would be a very infrequent occurrence though. But if the trap can't be handled in user mode, that probably rules it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not undefined as long as you don't dereference the pointer past either end.

`[0]` is the start, not `[1]`. `[-1]` is one before `[0]`.

The `&a[b]` syntax is treated by the compiler as exactly the same thing as `a + b`.

Comment: `&array[0] + 8` is defined, but `array[8]` _is not_.

Comment: **subscription is a dereference operation**: `a[i]` is the same as `*(a+i)`.

Comment: *And yet it is defined behavior, because a pointer is a perfectly legal random iterator.* My point is that there appears to be an escape clause in the standard that says that applying `&` to the result of `[]` *omits* the dereference operation and transforms it into pointer math. I don't own a copy of the standard or I'd look it up for you. Again, were you correct, then pointers could not be legal random iterators.

Comment: Anyway: `int a[2]; a-1;` is illegal, as you are trying to compute the address of an array element **that does not exist and that is not one-past-the-end**. The only "pseudo-element address" that you can compute is the one just past the end, here `a + 2`.